# Incorporar SET @acumulador=0; dentro de la consulta PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

no se donde incorporar `SET @acumulador=0;` dentro de la consulta PDO, ya que en MySQL la pruebo y funciona.

```
SET @acumulador=0;        

$sentencia=$conexion->prepare("SELECT id_cliente_cc, id_contribuyente ,fecha, concepto, debe, haber, @acumulador:=(debe-haber+@acumulador) AS saldos, ver FROM cta_cte_clientes WHERE id_contribuyente = $id_contribuyente AND ver = $ver ORDER BY cta_cte_clientes.fecha ASC");
```

Comment: Hola. PDO no funciona como los procedimientos almacenados de la base de datos (eso no significa que desde PDO no puedas llamar procedimientos almacenados y pasarle parámetros). Si quieres incorporar una variable en PDO, ponla como un marcador y luego usa `bindParam` para pasar el valor de la variable. Además, ¿qué sentido tiene un *acumulador* en una consulta de este tipo? Realmente no queda claro el problema. ¿No estarás confundiendo una consulta `SELECT` con un procedimiento almacenado o una función de la base de datos?

Comment: Ante todo muchas gracias por tu respuesta ...

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución y me funciona:

```
    $conexion->exec("SET @acumulador = 0;");
    $sentencia = $conexion->prepare("
        SELECT id_cliente_cc, id_contribuyente, fecha, concepto, debe, haber, (@acumulador := (debe - haber + @acumulador)) AS saldos, ver
        FROM cta_cte_clientes
        WHERE id_contribuyente = :id_contribuyente AND ver = :ver
        
    ");

    $sentencia->bindParam(':id_contribuyente', $id_contribuyente);
    $sentencia->bindParam(':ver', $ver);
    $sentencia->execute();
    $ctas_ctes=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sentencia->closeCursor();
```